# HTML5 Video with full cross browser compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, responsive-design, html5-video

I would like some guidance on the best proven method of creating a HTML5 video  section on my website that is fully cross browser compatible, works in a responsive layout ( so not fixed dimensions ) and also support IOS/ipad and other mobile devices. I have looked at several articles including (http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html).
I have tried mediaelement.js and Video.js and I have still had problems on older Internet Explorer Browsers ( specifically IE8 and below ) IE9 works fine. If some body could point me in the correct direction for achieving this with HTML5 video it will be a great help as im just not getting where I am going wrong!
Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, did you try the technique from dive into html5 where you use Flowplayer to play a flash version of your video for IE8 and below?

Code and working example is at the very end of http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

The example on the page seems to work well for me on IE7 and IE8, though I'm testing on a virtual box on a Mac so that might change something.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

### Cross-Browser HTML Video Code

Below is a fully **cross-browser** HTML5 video player code-set you can use that offers the "possibility" to support many older plugins and players of videos in older browsers. **It uses the latest HTML5 design** but adds in older `'object'` and `'embed'` elements for older browsers.

```
<figure aria-labelledby="videocaption3">
    <!-- VIDEO: The HTML5 'video' element is the primary source of the various video fallback elements below. Older browsers like IE 5-8 (using ActiveX) that do not recognize the 'video' HTML5 element will try and load the 'object' element version instead. -->
    <video 
        id="video3" 
        controls="controls" 
        preload="metadata" 
        style="width:320px;height:180px;border:none;outline:none;" 
        title="My Video" 
        aria-label="My Video">
        <!-- SOURCE: In this old ActiveX version, Microsoft Windows in Internet Explorer used the object ActiveX form while all other browsers used the 'embed' element below as fallback. -->
        <source src="video3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="video3.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <!-- OBJECT: In this old ActiveX version, Microsoft Windows in Internet Explorer used the object ActiveX form while all other browsers used the 'embed' element below as fallback. -->
        <object 
            id="object3" 
            name="object3" 
            data="video3.wmv" 
            type="video/x-ms-wmv" 
            style="width: 320px;height: 180px;border: none;outline: none;" 
            title="My Video" 
            aria-label="My Video">
                <!-- EMBED: In this old version, non-Internet Explorer, older, non-HTML5 browsers would recognize this fallback 'embed' version element and call their plugins and players to display the file below. Additional fallback in the form of a 'noembed' element with alert text would trigger for those user agents that do not support multimedia or the embed tag (as it was never part of an official HTML release). I recommend you use this old syntax if you are supporting older browsers that do not understand the newer HTML5 elements. -->
                <embed 
                       id="embed3" 
                       src="video3.wmv" 
                       type="video/x-ms-wmv" 
                       style="width: 320px;height: 180px;border: none;outline: none;" 
                       title="My Video" 
                       aria-label="My Video">
                    <noembed>-->
                    <!-- FALLBACK TEXT ALERT: If the user agent does not support video, give them a simple text alert below. -->
                    Sorry, your browser does not support this video.
                    </noembed>
                </embed>
        </object>
    </video>
    <!-- CAPTION: Captions wrap around the video elements the same as img, picture, and audio elements. -->
    <figcaption id="videocaption3"><small>"My Video"</small></figcaption>
</figure>
```

This code base should support HTML5 browsers that support the `'video'` element, and a wide range of older browsers going back to 2000 and older, which prior to HTML5, only supported the `'embed'` or `'object'` elements. In the old days, 'object' was used for ActiveX plugins in IE, and 'embed' for Netscape 4 (as well as later user agents that came on the scene). 'object' and 'embed' are still supported in HTML5, though they will rely on players/plugins/ActiveX to play multimedia. The 'video' element is native to most modern browsers now, but only works reliably in newer HTML5 supporting browsers (IE9-11, for example). Most HTML5 browsers (post-2010) should support the 'video' element and ignore the other two types, however. If they do not, they will fall back to the other elements as long as they both support the move encoding type and have a player installed to play it.

PROBLEMS

The main issues you may have playing *cross-browser videos* is NOT the HTML but the numerous versions of older browsers, deprecated players installed (or not installed), movie encoded types supported, and operating system (Mac vs Windows vs ?). Compound this with the limited mobile browser support, and you really need to deliver video from a reliable embedded 3rd party service, like YouTube. Often, many older browsers will simply not support the video encoding you supply. In other cases the operating system limits support of movie types. Example, `.wmv` was used for Windows long ago, and Quicktime `.mov` for Macs.

Many older browsers after 2004 started supporting `.flv` or Flash movies to deal with this cross-browser movie problem. Flash `.flv` at one time offered the widest support for video in webpages as almost everyone had Flash installed at one time (c. 2008). With the Flash player now deprecated in 2017, you cannot rely on that now, either. That is why use of the HTML5 'video' element is your best starting point for widest adoption.

Today, there are lots of newer alternative video players which help in supporting video in newer browsers, just not the older ones. If you do try and provide a cross-browser solution, I recommend, you try and stay with `.mp4` to cover most modern browsers and players, as well as a few older ones. Be realistic and design a solution that tries to target a specific group, rather than a universal set which would be very hard to do with the multitude video players going back the past 20 years.